# How do I print the binarys of a hex?

Tags: c

For example 0x19 is 00011001 in binary. I tried using printf %08x, but that gives me 00000019 as the output. How do I get it to print 00011001 instead?

Comment: Write your own function for that.

Comment: use [itoa,utoa](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man3/itoa.3avr.html)(non-standard) E.g. `char bits[32+1]; printf("%s\n", itoa(0x19, bits, 2));`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i=0; i<32; i++) putchar((x&(1<<(31-i)))?'1':'0');
```

Answer (score 0):

If itoa(non-standard function) can be used environment, can be written as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main( void ){
    char bits[CHAR_BIT*sizeof(unsigned)+1];
    itoa((int)0x19, bits, 2);
    int len = strlen(bits);
    if(len < 8)//%08
        printf("%0*d%s\n", 8-len, 0, bits);
    else
        printf("%s\n", bits);
    return 0;
}
```